# Is there a way to ignore the counter in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I want my for loop to not do the i++ if a certain condition applies.

```
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j = j+2) {
                int n = (int)(Math.random()*(474))+1;
                    if(!myList.contains(n)) {
                        myList.add(n);
                        myList.add(n);
                    }
                    else {
                        //Do not do i++ and j = j+2
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could just use a while loop, and then only increment the counter when you want to.

Answer (score 7):

> I want my for loop to not do the i++ if a certain condition applies.

Then you probably don't want a `for` loop, you probably want a `while` that only increments in the opposite of the condition where you didn't want the `for` to. I'd do an example, but it's unclear how you want the condition of the inner loop to affect the outer. The general form of this is:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < limit) {
    if (/* Condition where you should increment */) {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Be careful with the condition, to make sure you don't end up endlessly looping.

Or sometimes looping backward is a better choice, but I don't think that applies in this case.

Comment: how would I do this for both for loops?

Comment: @user3472686: That depends entirely on how you want them to relate, which is why I couldn't do an example with two loops. It's not at all clear how you want the condition in the inner loop (which is repeated several times for each of the outer loop's iterations) to decide whether the outer loop's counter is incremented. But fundamentally, what it comes down to is: Increment the counters when it's appropriate to do so. The rest is problem-specific logic.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to move the i++ from the iterator slot. You do not need to fully qualify a for() statement. I.E. for(;;) is legal in java.

```
for (int i = 0; i < r; ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j = j+2) {
            int n = (int)(Math.random()*(474))+1;
                if(!myList.contains(n)) {
                    myList.add(n);
                    myList.add(n);
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    //Do not do i++ and j = j+2
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test the condition in the for loop using the ternary operator and only change the counter variable when the condition is true. This means that you would need to move the condition variable outside the loop. But you could write something like this

```
for( int i = 0; i < r; cond ? i++ : i )
{
  .... 
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < r; ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c; ) {
            int n = (int)(Math.random()*(474))+1;
                if(!myList.contains(n)) {
                    myList.add(n);
                    myList.add(n);
                    i++;
                    j = j+2;
                }
    }
}
```